# Binding two class properties with TableView column in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, binding, tableview

I have following class:

```
public class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public StringProperty getName() {
        return new SimpleStringProperty(firstName.get() + " " + lastName.get()); 
    }
}
```

Then I have a TableView where I display both names in one column:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Person> personTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> name;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getName());

    personTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldVal, newVal) -> showDetails(newVal));
}
```

And right now I can make changes to my Person object but they aren't displayed in TableView column. When I open edit window again I see new values but in my TableView I see old ones. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do

```
public class Person {

    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();

    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person() {

        name.bind(Bindings.concat(firstName, " ", lastName));
        // existing code...
    }

    // existing code...

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
}
```

and then you can do

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Person, String> name;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());
}
```

Alternatively, you can omit the full name entirely from the `Person` class and just create the binding where you need it in the cell value factory:

```
name.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> Bindings.concat(
    cellData.getValue().firstNameProperty(),
    " ",
    cellData.getValue().lastNameProperty()));
```